# \index add spaces in text

Tags: indexing

I am writing a document with many indexed entries. I noted that this adds extra unwanted space in the text. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
Here.
The statement.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
Here.
\index{1}
\index{2}
\index{3}
\index{4}
\index{5}
The statement.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image: and the result is]

I can solve the problem by adding a `%` after every `\index{}` , but I wonder if there is a better solution... (I have more than 2000 index entries)

Comment: index does not add space, you are adding space with the linebreak, so a `%` after `Here.` is the most natural fix

Answer (score 2):

`\index` does not add space, you are adding space with the linebreak, so a `%` after `Here.` and the `\index` commands is the most natural fix, however you could insert an `\unskip` to remove a space before `\index` using a command hook as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\AddToHook{cmd/index/before}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
Here.
The statement.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
Here.
\index{1}
\index{2}
\index{3}
\index{4}
\index{5}
The statement.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa no the space hacks essentially move a single space before to a single space after but then don't stop subsequent ones building up.

Comment: @campa sure, but the latter case is the one the space hacks are designed for

Comment: Always adding `\unskip` before an index entry isn't always the safest approach.  There are situations when it's more reliable to input the index term *before* the term in the text, particularly when it's unclear where a page may break, and it's desirable to avoid an off-by-one page number in the index.  `%`, though a nuisance, is more flexible.